# Window get transparent

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, window, transparency

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04, after changing display from external screen to internal in my laptop my Firefox window get a little bit transparent.

The only one window which I set to have transparency is "xfce4-terminal 0.6.3", by it's own configuration. I didn't play with transparency of any other programs or system settings, if there is any.

The same kind of strange transparency has been before few times with Nautilus window.

[image: Transparent firefox window so we can see wallpaper under it]

Why is it happen? Where can I adjust and play with these settings of transparency, or is it just a strange bug? If so, where and how can I report this bug?

After reboot everything goes back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, but you can try to play with this Settings:

[image]

You can report a bug here https://bugzilla.xfce.org/buglist.cgi?component=Decorations&product=Xfwm4&resolution=---

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that is not a bug , but a feature in xfce where , when you scroll down on the titlebar of a window , the opacity of the window decreases .

To revert this just scroll up on the title bar to increase opacity.

Hope it helps. !!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting that.

I have had this problem two (maybe three) times.

Though unsure, I think something flickered when problem occurred.  It's so quick and unexpected it's hard to tell what happened.  May look like when xfwm is restarted (unsure). Anyway:

- The first time I worked around it by closing the affected window.
- The second time closing the window was not an option. I opened a terminal and typed

  xfwm4 --replace &

You may just press Alt-F2 and type `xfwm4 --replace` there.

The first time, I wondered if [I Accidentally](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally) some key shortcut I was unaware of.

Tuknutx may be right in suspecting a bug in xfwm.